How to make an "No condition" query in firebase database?
How can I write query to check if a field is existed in a document like in the attachment ? Currently in my code when I leave the operator empty the error message pops up:

FirebaseError: Unknown field filter op.



I did try many ways like !=, >= and <=  but didn't work because I'm querying more than one object key in a single query so I think the approach of using "No Condition" query seems to be more feasible

Does this answer your question? Check if value exists in firebase DB

Are you trying to find documents with that field? Or documents without that field? As Yasha_ops said, the latter isn't possible. But to find documents with the field, you can specify any value. for example - commonly specify null: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#value_type_ordering

I'm trying to find documents with specific fields but it seems orderBy doesn't let me process on two documents with same object key

If you're trying to find documents without a specific field, as Yasha_ops said, that isn't possible. See Check if value exists in firebase DB
But to find documents with the field, you can specify any value. for example - commonly specify null as that is the first "value" in the sort order of fields.
